# Takes a lot time to download and display images

Tags: android

I'm using Asynctask to download and display images and texts in my app. So when I run, it takes almost 1 to 3 minutes to download all and show them. gotta mention that it holds the activity and show it after the download task. In summery: I'm downloading json parts in the DownloadTask class extending Asynctask and inside of Downloadtask's onPostExecute trying to get the Texts and downloading the image Using another class called DownloadImage extending Asynctask again.

downloadTask class:

```
public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String,Integer ,String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
            String result = "";
            URL url;
            HttpURLConnection connection = null;

            try {

                url = new URL(strings[0]);
                connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
                int data = reader.read();
                while (data != -1) {
                    char current = (char) data;
                    result += current;
                    data = reader.read();
                }

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                Log.i("erro", e.toString());

            } catch (IOException io) {
                Log.i("erro", io.toString());


            } catch (Exception hooy) {
                Log.i("yes", hooy.toString());
            }
            return result;
        }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(strings[0]);
        String getMain = jsonObject.getString("articles");
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(getMain);
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    DownloadImage downloadImage = new DownloadImage();
                    JSONObject item = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    String desc = item.getString("description");
                    String image = item.getString("urlToImage");
                    String title = item.getString("title");
                    String url = item.getString("url");
                    urls.add(url);
                    Bitmap getImg = downloadImage.executeOnExecutor(THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, image).get();
                    Articles article = new Articles(getImg, title, desc);
                    articles.add(article);
                    recycleAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    Log.i("hey", Integer.toString(jsonArray.length()));
                }

                Log.i("hey", Integer.toString(recycleAdapter.getItemCount()));

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.i("erro", e.toString());
            }

        }
```

image method:

```
public static class DownloadImage extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Bitmap>{
        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... strings) {
            String result = "";
            URL url;
            HttpURLConnection connection;
            try{
                url = new URL(strings[0]);
                connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();

                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
                return bitmap;

            }catch (Exception e){return null;}

        }
```

onCreate method:

```
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
recycleAdapter = new RecycleAdapter(articles,getApplicationContext(),urls);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(recycleAdapter);

        try{
            DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask();
            String result = downloadTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR,"https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?q=bitcoin&apiKey=0310302f495d452ab7bc5e77db8dd0c0").get();

        }catch (Exception e){
            String err = (e.getMessage()==null)?"somethin wrong":e.getMessage();
            Log.e("erroor:",err);
        }
}
```

Comment: Try to use Glide library for images?

Comment: is there any specific reason of why you are downloading the image and showing it?

Comment: Try this library https://github.com/bumptech/glide

Comment: Can you please provide the amount of time take to load data from your url with help of postman ? Might there is chances delay from server side.

Comment: Those are nearly all the same images. Are you checking if you already downloaded one?

Comment: You are using get() on an asynctask. With that it is not async anymore. Your app freezes. Do away with the get() and use the asynctask in a normal way. Use onPostExecute() to place and handle the download.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two reasons why downloading that json takes so long.

First you read byte by byte.

Better take a BufferedReader so you can use the readLine() member as json is text.

Further you are concatenating String's. That takes time. Better use a StringBuilder.

And dont download the images twice. Check!

And do away with .get(). Use the tasks async.

Answer (score 1):

Use Glide library for display image.

Import library in app/build.gradle

```
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.6.1'
```

In your recycler view image

```
ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.image_view);

String image_url = "https://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/s--yDtXY-I4--/c_fill,fl_progressive,g_center,h_900,q_80,w_1600/pj5jc9ntilzdb4dfnivl.png";

RequestOptions options = new RequestOptions()
            .placeholder(R.drawable.place_holder_img)
            .error(R.drawable.place_holder_img);

Glide.with(context).load(image_url).apply(options).into(imageView);
```

Comment: I think another answer was suggesting about glide. But i think there is delay in server response.

Comment: Honestly, I wanted to avoids using libraries. is it the only way?

Comment: Glide is provided by google. It is very light weight library. Glide have good cache management. This is really fast image loading library. I suggest you to use this.

Answer (score 0):

Your reading one by one bytes .Better to create a buffer of 1024 bytes and ready 1024 bytes by read method then u will do the process .Then it will increase your performance or decrease ur delay time.

Replace the block (in the downloadTask class) :

```
while (data != -1) {
                    char current = (char) data;
                    result += current;
                    data = reader.read();
                }
```

with the new block and try it:

```
byte[] bytes=new byte[1024];
byte[] new_bytes=null;
int new_byte_len=0;
int ch=1;
while(ch!=-1)
{
  ch=is.read(bytes,0,1024);
  if((new_bytes==null)&&(ch>0)){
    new_bytes=new byte[ch];
    System.arrayCopy(bytes,0,new_bytes,0,ch);
  }     
  else if(ch>0){
    byte temp_byte[]=new byte[new_bytes.length];
    System.arrayCopy(new_bytes,0,temp_byte,0,new_bytes.length);
    int new_len=new_bytes.length+ch;
    new_bytes=new byte[new_len];
    System.arrayCopy(temp_byte,0,new_bytes,0,temp_byte.length);
    System.arrayCopy(bytes,0,new_bytes,temp_byte.length,ch);
  }

  if(ch<1024) break;  

}

result=new String(new_bytes);
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use thread while downloading the image from the server

```
new Thread() {
                        public void run() {
                            try {
                                URL url, url1;
                                url = new URL( Thumb_Img );
                                url1 = new URL( Full_Img );
                                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                               InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();

                               bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream( is );

                            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            handler.post( runnableUI )
                            ;
                        }
                    }.start();



    Runnable runnableUI = new Runnable(){
                    public void run() {
                        Glide.with( getActivity() ).asBitmap()
                                .load( Thumb_Img )          

                    }
                };
```

Comment: I tried threads but didn't do the trick. If you have any specific way, I would be thankful if you show me.

Comment: you are downloading the image in internal storage or only from server and displaying it on Image view? if only setting the image then you should use glide or Picasso library for setting the image it works fast.

Comment: did you use glide or Picasso like this: Glide.with( getActivity() ).asBitmap()
                            .load( Thumb_Img )
                            .into( thumb_img );

Comment: set the image like this in your adapter class